# What is better: add your views using XML or code?

Tags: android, xml, performance

What is better for performance in Android application: add your View-elements using XML or Java code?

Comment: Slightly faster adding in your code (the layout inflater of course also adds the views in code), because you're cutting out the XML validation and parsing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Difference in performance is not really observable, but for developing sake its better to keep it in XML. Then it's easier for You to develop adaptative UI supporting many screens. What's more it seperates code implementation from designing UI, what is always a nice thing and makes your code easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you declare the XML layout properly there is no noticeable difference.
But i will suggest to use the XML because using that you can actually show what the layout is going to look like and it give you more clear idea about your UI.
One more advantage is that when you are giving the multiple resolution support for you application UI it will help you a lot.